# Inexpensive mods for decathlon 7 speed road bike

Tags: shimano, chain, drivetrain, cleaning, lubricant

I have a Decathlon Triban RC 100 Flat bar. It is an entry level gravel/roadie that I have had for over two years now. It comes with a Shimano Tourney 1x7 set up, which is quite underwhelming. However, I couldn't expect more for the money. I would like to convert it to a drop bar setup, which means having to change the handlebar, shifting and braking mechanisms.

I am a rookie rider, and ride for leisure only. As much as I would love to upgrade it, it is purely for getting a better cycle out of the frame, and not as a competitive effort. I have a few questions.

1. Should I do it at all?
2. Some inexpensive drive train suggestions would be very very welcome.
3. While I understand the need for chain lube, good chain lube is hard to come by where I stay (India). Are there ingredients with which I could concoct my own, without burning a hole in my pockets. I ride in all seasons, and use new, fully synthetic motor oil, from a bottle (not the used, black stuff from vehicles). Motor oil is sacrilege for all serious riders, so suggestions on that front would be welcome. The problem with fully synthetic motor oil is it is equally hard to get off during chain cleaning, so I might have to switch to a dedicated lube only.
4. The saddle is quite hard, the way I like it. However, with use, the sponge has started wearing off. Would it make sense to switch to a hard plastic /carbon fiber saddle?

I am a rookie, please counsel me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Switching to drop bar and brifters, to the best of my knowledge, is pretty much the opposite of an inexpensive mod.

Comment: Just regarding chain lube (which should be a separate question really) - (i) It's always hard to get lube off, whether dedicated or cheap (ii) you might want to get dry lube for the appropriate seasons, and only use oily (wet) lube at wet times of year (my understanding is that most of India has very seasonal rain, but there are probably exceptions) (iii) clean motor oil isn't that bad, but is a bit thick.  Scooter gear oil might be more appropriate as (checking amazon.in) proper bike oil does seem hard to get, but sewing machine oil should work well and looks to be readily available

Comment: @Burki please consider elaborating that as an answer.

Comment: Chain waxing is a solution if you want to avoid oil completely.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-to-chain-wax or move that to a new separate question.

Comment: Motor oil/ATF as chain lube   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43642/

Comment: Chainsaw bar lube https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37399/how-good-or-bad-would-chainsaw-bar-lubricant-be-as-a-bicycle-chain-lube

Comment: This Q&A forum works best if you ask only one question.

Answer (score 6):

It all comes down to your budget.  I'd love a new bike, but it would be a significant cost.

Instead you should address specific points

- What bothers/hurts you?  The saddle is one of the three main contact points, and finding the right one or a better one is worth doing.  Ride comfort improves.   Padded bib-shorts/gloves help too.
- Upgrading the drive train can be expensive - 1x7 and possibly a freewheel means you've got no single piece to change.  Instead you'd need a new wheel hub, cassette, chain, derailleur, and right-hand shifter to get more gears.
  All that costs money.  If you had a starting point like a donor bike then that helps - I once picked up a free bike that had a two-part frame after being in an accident.  The transmission and brakes and levers were used-but-workable, so I filed the abrasions off and 5 years later I'm still riding with those parts.
- What is worn?  Simply replacing worn parts that are a bit faulty can improve your ride.  No need to upgrade - a shifter that doesn't reliably click can be a source of irritation.

Converting to a drop bar can be done but its cash-heavy.  Again, a donor bike can ease the barriers, but there's a chance the frame's geometry will be different between models.  Try sitting on your bike and hold some imaginary hoods located in front of your flatbar - your torso will be lower and more stretched out.

If you have the space, a second bike is perfectly reasonable.  Look around for a used road bike to buy, and try it out.  If it doesn't suit you, sell it on for about what it cost you.   New bikes suffer devaluation, old ones generally hold their value fine.   50 pounds or 100 dollars is a small cost if you can recover it later.

Get a feel for other bikes by test riding them.  Ask other riders you know if you may have a try of their bike.  I have my "wet day bike" which is 2x7 80's dropbar, and at least 4 people from work have tried it out.  Some went on to buy road bikes after owning MTB, and some didn't but they have a better idea of what they want.

Final "upgrades" are for the data nerds

1. fit a small bike computer on your handlebars for realtime display of speed.   Seeing 19.7 km/h motivates you to push for 20 km/h   Cateye wired ones are cheap.
2. get into something like strava or similar and start tracking your rides.  Personal Progress-over-time is a motivator ("That's my fastest commute ever! ")  as is competition with others ("I'm in the top 2000 riders on that segment!" )   Strava free and a smartphone is not expensive, no need for head units and power meters etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. You probably don't need to change the brakes. I'm in the U.S., and looking up prices on a U.S.-based website, it looks like you can get Tourney STI levers for $85, and a new handlebar for $25 (note: this supposes that the handlebar has the same clamp diameter as your current bar, which it might not). Add another $10 for bar tape, and $20 for new cables and cable housings. So, $140 if you do all the work yourself. Is that worth it? Only you can answer that question.
2. Not sure how to answer this.
3. People have used all kinds of lubricants as chain lubes, so I wouldn't be embarrassed about using motor oil, but that's not necessarily ideal. Wax-based lube keeps the chain cleaner, but it's sacrificial–you need to reapply pretty often. That said, the bottle of wax lube that I've got has lasted me over 10 years. I have to imagine that there are online bike stores either in India or that ship to India.
4. Ordinarily, only the weeniest weight-weenies (and BMX riders) use completely unpadded saddles. You can probably find a new saddle with some padding that will hold up better.

Comment: We should have a separate question about motor oil https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43642/ comes close.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't try to upgrade that bike. You'll need a new rear hub and new drivetrain. If you buy them off-the-shelf, it will cost you
   as much as a new, entry level bike having, say, 3x8 groupset, labor
   cost excluded. I'd sell the bike, and buy a second hand one that
   fits better to my taste, if that suits you too...
2. There is no cheap way of upgrade possible when "brifters" involved; yet Ltwoo groupset is damn good considering the price.
3. Engine oil is fine, if you have nothing else. But waxing is much better then anything else! There is an Australian guy on Youtube which is a big advocate for it, watch his videos. It's cheaper, too.
4. Saddles are hard, we all live with it. Get good bibs, and don't bother. I almost tried every saddle, from 3$ to 300$. After 100 km's, they feel all the same to me.